# Should Change Tracking Proxies work if I use a Database First model?

Tags: entity-framework-5

Should Change Tracking Proxies work if I use a Database First model?

After creating the model with the database first designer, though navigational properties are marked virtual, other properties are not.

If I edit the classes so that the properties are virtual (and of course public, not sealed, use ICollection where needed and remove initializing of navigators from the classes constructor), this will get overwritten if I ever update the model from the database while within the designer.

And, if I make all (what I believe are) the necessary changes to allow for Change Tracking Proxies, when I test with "x is IEntityWithChangeTracker" it still returns false.

So, either I'm really doing something wrong or I'm doing something that wasn't meant to be. I hope it's the former.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF6.x uses  System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses for its IEntityWithChangeTracker. If you use this version of  IEntityWithChangeTracker, it will work. Using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.IEntityWithChangeTracker was my problem here.